# Web cannot access the root directory of apache virtual host

Tags: apache, laravel-4

I am running apache. I have a virtual host named mis.chaatz.com. However if I typed mis.abc.com. It returns "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server". However, if I type mis.abc.com/login, it can retuns webpage. I guess something is wrong with my apache config. Try all days, no luck.

The config is as follows:

I have a host file in /windows/system32/drivers/etc

```
127.0.0.1 mis.abc.com
```

The httpd.conf is as follows:

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  Allow from all
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"

<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>  

<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule> 

# the following the document root of the mis.chaatz.com 

<Directory "C:\apache24\htdocs\new_project\laravel\public\laravel1\public">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And the httpd-vhosts conf is as follows:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\apache24\htdocs\new_project\laravel\public\laravel1\public"
  ServerName mis.abc.com    
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following which has always worked for me on Mac OSX. I do not configure the `httpd.conf` at all. What I do vaguely remember is that Apache reads forward slashes in the path and you have backslashes. I would say try it without the `httpd.conf` edit you made.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot C:/apache24/htdocs/new_project/laravel/public/laravel1/public
   ServerName mis.abc.com   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, after trace step by step. I finally find out that the problem exist in this config. 
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
If I change the index.html to index.php above. Then the problem is solved.